# Find the interior, the closure, the boundary the set $A=\left \{ m+\frac{1}{n}|m,n\: \in\mathbb{N}^{*} \right \}$ on $\mathbb{R}?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was asked to find the interior, closure, boundary of the set $A=\left \{ m+\frac{1}{n}|m,n\: \in\mathbb{N}^{*} \right \}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. This is my 1st try:

(i) $int(A)=\emptyset$. Since $\forall x_0\in  A,\forall r>0:\mathbf{B}(x_0,r)=(x_0-r;x_0+r)$ contains irrational numbers which are not in A, so $\mathbf{B}(x_0,r)\nsubseteq A$.

(ii) $\overline{A}=A\cup \left \{ 1,2,3,\dots \right \}=A\cup\left \{ 1 \right \}$

- $\forall x_0\in A,\forall r>0:\mathbf{B}(x_0,r)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ since $\mathbf{B}(x_0,r)$ always contains at least one element $x_0$ in $A$. Thus, $\forall x_0\in A,x_0\in\overline{A}$.
- $\forall m\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, Let's consider the sequence $(a_n)$ where $a_n=m+\frac{1}{n},\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, we see that $a_n\in A,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $a_n\rightarrow m$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Thus, $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}^{*}, m\in\overline{A}$.
- $\forall x_0>1$ and $x_0\notin A$, then there is $m_0,n_0\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ such that $x_0\in\left ( m_0+\frac{1}{n_0+1};m_0+\frac{1}{n_0} \right )$. Let's choose $r=min\left \{ x_0-\left(m_0+\frac{1}{n_0+1}\right);\left(m_0+\frac{1}{n_0}\right)-x_0 \right \}>0$, we will have $\mathbf{B}(x_0;r)\cap A=\emptyset$. Thus, $\forall x_0>1$ and $x_0\notin A$, then $x_0\notin \overline{A}$.
- $\forall x_0<1$, let's choose $r=1-x_0>0$, we have $\mathbf{B}(x_0;r)=(x_0-r;x_0+r)=(2x_0-1;1)$. Clearly, $\mathbf{B}(x_0;r)\cap A=\emptyset$ since $inf(A)=1$. Thus, $\forall x_0<1$, $x_0\notin\overline{A}$.

Thus, we have: $\overline{A}=A\cup \left \{ 1,2,3,\dots \right \}=A\cup\left \{ 1 \right \}$

(iii) $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus int(A)=\overline{A}\setminus\emptyset=\overline{A}=A\cup \{1\}$.

Is my answer good enough? If anything is wrong or needs to be added or corrected, please let me know! I'm not really sure about my reasoning for finding the closure of A.
And for all limit points, I think it should be $\{1,2,3,...\}$, right? Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}^*$ ?

Comment: @Lilla Sorry, you mean $\mathbb{N}^{*}$ in the set $A$ or in my guess about the limit points? If it's about the limit points, I haven't actually finished it yet, those are just first thoughts. I think if I fix each $m$, and with every $r>0$, then $\mathbf{B}(m,r)$ can contain some elements in $A\setminus \{m\}$ (By using  the Archimedean property). Isn't it right?

Comment: in the set $A$.

Comment: @Lilla hmm That is the content of the problem I asked! I think there is $\frac{1}{n}$, then $n\neq 0$ makes more sense! Any problems with that?

Comment: Got it.........